# Form initial data does not display in template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I have a form with some fields that have initial values. After run my application, the form appears but its fields initial values don't display, just an empty form.

I put a `{{ profile_form.initial }}` in my template to make sure that the form has initial data. It returns a dict with initial data:

```
{'local_number': 'test-local-number', 'last_name': 'test-last-name', 'phone': 'test-phone', 'zip_code': 'test-zip-code', 'city': 'test-city', 'user': <User: testuser>, 'street': 'test-street', 'first_name': 'test-first-name'}
```

Here is my code:

## forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    initial_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'street',
                      'local_number', 'city', 'zip_code']
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'street',
                  'local_number', 'city', 'zip_code')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
        initial = kwargs.pop('initial', {})
        for key in self.initial_fields:
            if hasattr(self.instance, key):
                initial[key] = initial.get(key) or getattr(self.instance, key)
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

## views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        profile_form = MyForm(
            request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
        context.update({'profile_form': profile_form})
        }
        return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

## template.html

```
<form class="animated-form" action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form.initial }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your form's `__init__` method. If you pass an `instance` to a model form, the form is already filled with the instance as initial.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right :) After delete this "custom initialization", nothing changes, I'll remove it from my code then. It's not the problem solution but still very useful comment:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.POST` is an empty dict if no POST data were submitted. You must use `request.POST or None`, otherwise, it will be understood as "form submitted with every fields blank" and initialize won't be taken into account.

You also shouldn't call `is_valid()` on a form that was not submitted.

```
...
profile_form = MyForm(
    request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile)
if request.method == 'POST' and profile_form.is_valid():
    ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result as above:(

Comment: I think you also shouldn't call `is_valid()` on a form that was not submitted. Try `if request.method == "POST" and profile_form.is_valid():`

Comment: How are you refreshing your page ? It might just be your browser that does not update the fields to "keep the data you entered". If you open your page in a new tab, it should prevent this behavior. You can also check the source code for inputs `value` attribute.

Comment: Yay! That's it, thank you! I wouldn't find out it myself:)